# Perl Blowfish/CBC Encryption and Decryption functions

Tags: perl, encryption, blowfish

New to Perl and Cryptography here. Does anyone have any simple Encrypt/Decrypt functions (using Blowfish or CBC) that encapsulate all the under-the-hood dirty work? I want to have one **fixed** KEY to use and be able to pass a string of **any** length for encryption.

For clarity, I want to encrypt credentials using the Encrypt function, save the result somewhere, and Decrypt it when needed... all the while using the same key.

I basically want to do this:

```
$fixedKey = "0123456789ABCDEF";
$plainText = "A string of any length..........";

$encryptedString = Encrypt($fixedKey, $plainText); 

$retrievedText = Decrypt($fixedKey, $encryptedString);
```

Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses Crypt::CBC for salting, padding and chaining, and it uses Crypt::Rijndael (AES) for encryption.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use Crypt::CBC qw( );

sub encrypt {
   my ($key, $plaintext) = @_;

   my $iv = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes(16);

   my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
      -cipher      => 'Rijndael',
      -literal_key => 1,
      -key         => $key,
      -iv          => $iv,
      -header      => 'none',
   );

   return $iv . $cipher->encrypt($plaintext);
}

sub decrypt {
   my ($key, $ciphertext) = @_;

   my $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, 16, '');

   my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
      -cipher      => 'Rijndael',
      -literal_key => 1,
      -key         => $key,
      -iv          => $iv,
      -header      => 'none',
   );

   return $cipher->decrypt($ciphertext);
}

{
   my $key = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes(32);
   say "Key: ", unpack "H*", $key;

   my $expect = 'secret';
   say "Plaintext: $expect";

   my $ciphertext = encrypt($key, $expect);
   say "Ciphertext: ", unpack "H*", $ciphertext;

   my $got = decrypt($key, $ciphertext);
   say "Plaintext: $got";
   say $expect eq $got ? "ok" : "not ok";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami... looks great, i will try it out!